# have error in run generic typescript function

Tags: typescript

i have a sample code for generics in typescript.

```
const variab = function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
    return arg;
  }

  let output = variab<string>("myString");
  console.log(output);
```

but in run have this error:

D:\practice2\index.ts:21
const variab = function identity(arg: Type): Type {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.13.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the native js compiler to run the `ts` file. My best guess is that you're just using `node index.ts` to run your file. But unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.

You'll need this npm package [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) to run your typescript files. You can install the module globally by running the following two commands

```js
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g ts-node
```

then you can run your file with
`ts-node index.ts` and it will work fine.
Else you can just run it inline via `npx ts-node index.ts` and it will produce the same result.
The code that you've written works perfectly fine and it produces the desired output. You can check that on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwE4EsECMYF4YDMCuYwUK4MKAJgKZglQCeAPACr0AOVAfABTIDmALhisOASiEiqMAN4BYAFAwlMJFSj4kYGPwDcCpQF8F+mABs1MEPihtr2eMjTpG0VGD48ARAFt6AZSg3Pk9RPUUzCxA2AEZ7RFQMRjB8b3QqJB4ANgBOUJNQSBBzADpTED5uKxtrPPCCiCKqUvLKmNEgA)

I recommend you to watch some beginner typescript tutorials on YouTube before getting started with TypeScript as they really help a lot.

Comment: thanks for your answer. run this code by npx ts-node index.ts